# Getting the first element of a bs4.element.ResultSet object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, set

So, I'm trying to get informations about a website using BeautifulSoup. The thing is, using findAll() I get a bs4.element.ResultSet object and I have to loop through it to get its elements. But I'm pretty sure I will get only one tag of it and I don't want to loop through a set which has only one element in it.

So my question is how do I get only the first and probably the unique element of a bs4.element.ResultSet object?

```
<div class="textinfo">
   <div class="author">A tale of <span><a href="/profile/89965">Edgar Allan Poe</a></span></div>
   <div class="category">Category: Horror</div>
   <div class="date">Date: 27/11/2008</div>
   <div class="votes">Votes <a href="/text/200811799/votes"><span id="votesmedia">10.00</span></a> </div>
</div>
```

These methods are inside a class thats why I'm using 'self'.

```
def getTales(self):
    talesLinks = self.file.readLinks(self.file.talePath)
    driver = browser.connectChrome()

    for link in talesLinks:
        headerTale = []
        driver.get(link)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

        #Probably I'll get only one div 'textinfo' for each link.
        header = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'textinfo'})
        self.getHeaderInfo(header, headerTale)

    driver.quit()
    print("chrome headless closed")

def getHeaderInfo(self, header, headerTale):

    # I don't want to loop because I know 'header' has only one element.
    for author in headerTale:
        author = header.findAll('div', {'class', 'author'})
        #...
        #...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first element use `find()` or `select_one()`

In your case instead of

```
header = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'textinfo'})
```

Try either of followings.

```
header = soup.find('div',class_='textinfo')
```

OR

```
header = soup.select_one('div.textinfo')
```

OR

```
 header = soup.find_all('div',class_='textinfo')[0]
```